# How can I get the insertion position of a TextBox when there is a selection?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If there is no selection in a TextBox, then the insertion position is equal to SelectionStart.

But if there **is** a Selection, then the insertion position might be at SelectionStart (right-to-left selection):

[image]

Or it might be at SelectionStart + SelectionLength (left-to-right selection):

[image]

How, then, does one figure out the insertion position of a TextBox when there is a selection?

Comment: At insertion the currently selected text is replaced with whatever you are inserting. So the insertion point is SelectionStart.

Comment: Well, whether it's called the caret, the cursor, or something else, I'm talking about the grey thing in my images above.

Comment: The native EDIT control doesn't have any way to let you find out.  Nobody can help you beyond this if you don't explain why it matters.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a way to *trick*, but there is no natural way of doing that.

If for example at given moment in application you know that the text in `TextBox` is selected  (no difference left-right or right-left),
you can do

```
textBox1.SelectionLength = 0; //this will clear a selection UI
```

After this line by calling

```
int caretPosition =  textBox1.SelectionStart;
```

will retrieve actually a `Caret` position to you.

By the way this is a  trick, so it's better to avoid these kind of solutions (may be there will be someone offering something else) and it's better to slightly rearrange the code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Great explanation on caret position here, best to call native API that way you don't break selection and other textbox functions (such as undo)

http://www.microbion.co.uk/developers/C%20position%20of%20caret.pdf